# How do I create a simple Gtk MessageDialog in Rust / gtk-rs?

Tags: rust, gtk3, gtk-rs

I am trying out gtk-rs and while there is certainly documentation available, it is much too hard to understand for a beginner. I just see many different impls and traits and generics, but there never are any code examples from which I can learn. Usually I look at code, use it, and then go through it line by line so I can understand it. But this isn't possible here.

Can somebody please help me?

I used to program in PyGTK and I found an old sample code:

```
def report_error(self, reason):
    dialog = Gtk.MessageDialog(Gtk.Window(), 0, Gtk.MessageType.INFO, Gtk.ButtonsType.OK, "You did something wrong")
    dialog.format_secondary_text(reason)
    dialog.run()
    dialog.destroy()
```

But how, just how can I do this in Rust/gtk-rs? I am completely lost.

Comment: Sorry to say, but this is offtopic, as you want us to either find a tutorial for you or act as a code-writing-service. Stackoverflow is neither of both. You may ask on the [rust forum](https://users.rust-lang.org/) or try some of the online tutorials from gtk-rs. Please take yourself the time to [learn rust](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/index.html) as well as it seems, that you don't have much experience with it. Building a GUI is too hard for your first experiments.

Comment: I apologize. :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[There is an example](http://gtk-rs.org/docs/gtk/) demonstrating a message box:

```
extern crate gtk;
use gtk::prelude::*;
use gtk::{ButtonsType, DialogFlags, MessageType, MessageDialog, Window};

fn main() {
    if gtk::init().is_err() {
        println!("Failed to initialize GTK.");
        return;
    }
    MessageDialog::new(None::<&Window>,
                       DialogFlags::empty(),
                       MessageType::Info,
                       ButtonsType::Ok,
                       "Hello World").run();
}
```

Comment: I looked everywhere, but not the start page of the crate. 
I did some more research on what each lines does and customized it to my needs. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You should always start from the `Documentation` link on the crate page on `crates.io`.